# Generate cards dynamically in a 3 column format using data in state variable of a class

Tags: reactjs

Not able to generate the cards dynamically in a column format. I am using the data in state variable and generating cards using map function which is ultimately being displayed as {cards} in return. I tried using Grid but was not able to solve the issue.

I am new to React js and would really appreciate any help to solve this problem.

This is the code I have written

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';

const styles = theme => ({
  card: {
    maxWidth: 345,
    marginLeft: 75,
    marginTop: 30,
  },
  media: {
    height: 140,
  },
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
});


class MediaCard extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      templatesInformation : [
        {
          id: 'temp1',
          image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500',
          title: 'Contemplative Reptile',
          typo: 'Template 1',
          description: 'This is template1. It is the most preferable one and is used by most of our customers.',
          previewLink: 'http://www.ijettcs.org/Volume3Issue6/IJETTCS-2014-12-08-96.pdf'
        },
        {
          id: 'temp2',
          image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500',
          title: 'Contemplative Reptile',
          typo: 'Template 2',
          description: 'This is template2. It is the most preferable one and is used by most of our customers.',
          previewLink: 'http://www.ijettcs.org/Volume3Issue6/IJETTCS-2014-12-08-96.pdf'
        },
        {
          id: 'temp3',
          image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500',
          title: 'Contemplative Reptile',
          typo: 'Template 3',
          description: 'This is template3. It is the most preferable one and is used by most of our customers.',
          previewLink: 'http://www.ijettcs.org/Volume3Issue6/IJETTCS-2014-12-08-96.pdf'
        },
        {
          id: 'temp4',
          image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500',
          title: 'Contemplative Reptile',
          typo: 'Template 4',
          description: 'This is template4. It is the most preferable one and is used by most of our customers.',
          previewLink: 'http://www.ijettcs.org/Volume3Issue6/IJETTCS-2014-12-08-96.pdf'
        },
      ]
    }
  }

  render(){

    const { classes } = this.props;

    const cards = this.state.templatesInformation.map((templateInfo) => {
      return(
        <Card className={classes.card} key = {templateInfo.id} class = "col s10">
          <CardMedia
            style = {{ height: 0, paddingTop: '56%'}}
            className={classes.media}
            image={templateInfo.image}
            title={templateInfo.title}
          />
          <CardContent>
            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
              {templateInfo.typo}
            </Typography>
            <Typography component="p">
              {templateInfo.description}
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
          <CardActions>
            <Button size="small" color="primary" href = {templateInfo.previewLink} target = "_blank">
              PREVIEW
            </Button>
          </CardActions>
        </Card>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={12}>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            {cards}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

MediaCard.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
export default withStyles(styles)(MediaCard);
```

Comment: What is the issue here. What you are getting as a output?

Comment: You are generating cards in a wrong place it should not be in the render function. you can make a function i.e cardRender which returns the cards.  then call it during render

Comment: @ravibagul91 I am getting all the four cards in a single column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
const cards = this.state.templatesInformation.map(templateInfo => {
      return (
        <Grid item xs={4}> // Added grid here - changed `xs={6}` -> `xs={4}` for 3 column format 
          <Card className={classes.card} key={templateInfo.id} > //remove class from here
            <CardMedia
              style={{ height: 0, paddingTop: "56%" }}
              className={classes.media}
              image={templateInfo.image}
              title={templateInfo.title}
            />
            <CardContent>
              <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                {templateInfo.typo}
              </Typography>
              <Typography component="p">{templateInfo.description}</Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions>
              <Button
                size="small"
                color="primary"
                href={templateInfo.previewLink}
                target="_blank"
              >
                PREVIEW
              </Button>
            </CardActions>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      );
    });

return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={12}>
          {cards}
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-zopck?fontsize=14)